# Android studio not recognising functions and reference to id problem

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I want to learn how to create android apps in android studio and I'm having some problems now.

**The problem is that my android studio does not recognize the id assigned in the xml file and does not recognize basic functions like setOnClickListener.**

I created button i layout xml file like this:

```
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/No_btn"
            style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Button.Borderless.Small"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/b2"
            android:textColor="#BD3F3F" />
```

When i try to reference to it in kotlin file like this:
`No_btn.setOnClickListener {}`
It just doesn't see the id or the function. I've already tried reinstalling the android studio and synchronizing project with Gradle files. Dunno what to do.

Comment: try using [`viewBinding`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) or `findViewById()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem you are facing is related to **Kotlin Synthetics** which was deprecated not long ago. 
 Many tutorials on YouTube use Kotlin Synthetics. Google suggested to [**migrate the Project to viewBindings**](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration). 
 Implementing viewBindings is easy and explained in the link above.
 
But for learning purposes **you can still use kotlin Synthetics** as long as you are on small projects.
Just add the **plugin** `id 'kotlin-android-extensions'` in **gradle.build** file and you will be able to reference the button as you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you create a variable first and declared its value?
2. Try implementing `View.OnClickListener`
3. Maybe your Java class isn't linked to the XML file. add `setContentView(R.layout.YOURXML);` to your Java file and make sure your XML has `tools:context=".YOURJAVA"`

Written in Java so I hope you will understand:

```
**import android.view.View;**

public class RegisterPage extends AppCompatActivity **implements View.OnClickListener** {
**private Button noBtn;**

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        **setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_page);**

        noBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.No_btn);
        noBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use No_btn or any other view in you Kotlin code, you either need to use findViewById or activate view binding in the gradle file:

```
val noBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.No_btn)
```

To add view binding to your app, follow [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding).